# sublimetextで検索結果のリアルタイム表示を抑止する

Tags: sublimetext

sublime text3 に20万行ぐらいのテキストデータを取り込んで全体やカーソル位置の近隣を検索しようとしているのですが、
1文字入力する度にエディタが評価→該当位置表示をしようとする為に入力が出来ません。
検索ボタンを押すまで評価をしない設定や便利なプラグインなどがあるでしょうか。

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 2):

検索文字入力枠の横（多分左）に「Highlight matches」のボタンがあったと思います。それを切り替えれば<kbd>Enter</kbd>を押すまでハイライトされなかったかと。